# iOS Internal Testing with testflight - how to do testing without "technical" role?

Tags: ios, testflight, beta-testing

I have a number of users from different department added to iOS developer program as "internal testers". Sometimes the app submission process has an error, generating scary emails like:

**iTunes Connect: Your app "app name" (Apple ID: 12345) has one or more issues**

Apparently these go to everyone marked as "technical role", which in my case includes people from UX and other department, which freaks them out.

**Is there a way to distribute apps using Apple Test Flight to users without them being assigned as technical role?**

Comment: i think you have to set them up as external testers then...

Comment: External testing requires a week + approval process, which would not always work for people who want the app right now.

Comment: That is Not completely true. After the App was approved once and you do Not make significant changes a new Build is available in mlnutes...

Comment: That's good to know, it's probably as long as your version is the same, like 1.2.3

Comment: i do not know how they decide if changes are significant or not. you are asked everytime you upload a new build: "did you make any significant changes...?" - you should be honest though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. To be internal tester, you have to be at least technical role.